# recursive formula for Schur polynomials

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I've got Schur polynomials of multivariables $x=x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots$defined as

$$\exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k z^k\right) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P_k(x) z^k$$

So, how can i get $ P_0(x)=1 $ ? And how can I get the formula for, for example $ P_{30}(x) $ ? How can i get recursive formula for this?

When I tried to expand this equation I get something like this:
$$\exp(x_1 z^1+x_2 z^2+x_3 z^3+\cdots) = P_0(x) $$
which isn't even similar to 1. And if I try to cut this expression in the way that I don't see the reason it would be correct, I get something like this:
$$\exp(x_1z^1) = P_0(x).$$
Still not 1. And I don't think it is even correct... Is it an assumption that $P_0=1$? How would You get recurisive formula for Schur polynomials then?

Comment: If you expand the series for exp, you'll immediatey get tah $P_0=1$.

Comment: $\exp(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^k z_k) = 1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^k z_k+1/2 *(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^k z_k))^2..$  how is it equal to 1?

Comment: It is not equal to $1$. Why would it be?! Ony its constantt term is equal to $1$.

Comment: What happens when you set $z=0.$

Comment: when i set z=0 then it is 1, but can i do this? what would i get $P_1$ and $P_2$ ?

Comment: You can equate "like terms" (which is the point that Mariano is making): the constant term can only come from terms that don't include $z$ on both sides of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\exp(u)=\sum_{i\geq0}u^i$, we have 
\begin{align}
\exp(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k z^k)&=\sum_{i\geq0}\frac{1}{i!}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k z^k\right)^i\\
&=1+z\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k z^{k-1}\right)+\frac{z^2}{2!}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k z^{k-1}\right)^2+\cdots
\end{align}
As every term after the first one has $z$ as a factor, the constant term in the sum is $1$, and that is $P_0$.
Similarly, all terms from the third one on are divisible by $z^2$, so the term involving $z$ comes from the secodn term and he coefficient of $z$ in the sum is $x_1$.
All terms after the fourth one are divisible by $z^2$, so the coefficient of $z^2$ in the whole sum is the sam as the coefficient of $z^2$ in $$1+z\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k z^{k-1}\right)+\frac{z^2}{2!}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k z^{k-1}\right)^2,$$ which is $x_2+x_1^2/2$.

The coefficient of $z^3$ is $\frac{x_1^3}{6}+x_2 x_1+x_3$ and comes fromthe first four terms, and so on.

Comment: Now i get how $P_0$ is equal to 1, but how would You get $P_1$ and $P_2$? It this $P_0$ multiplied by some factor?